# how to resolve missing maven-junction-plugin dependency: junction.exe?

Tags: maven

I'm trying to set up clean phase to use maven-junction-plugin as I'm building the project from both Linux and Windows. 
Here is my pom.xml section for junction plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.pyx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-junction-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unlink</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unlink</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <links>

                    <link>
                        <dst>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</dst>
                        <src>${WEB-INF}</src>
                    </link>
                </links>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But I got an error when I run mvn clean:

> Failed to execute goal com.pyx4j:maven-junction-plugin:1.0.3:unlink (unlink) on project webapp: Execution unlink of goal com.pyx4j:maven-junction-plugin:1.0.3:unlink failed: Plugin com.pyx4j:maven-junction-plugin:1.0.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find sysinternals:junction:exe:1.04 in http://myserver.com:8080/archiva/repository/internal was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of archiva.default has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

I'm using an internal archiva server for maven repository, and it does have maven-junction-plugin in the repository, but missing junction-1.04.exe, is there a way that I can add the downloaded junction-1.04.exe in archiva or .m2 cache for the junction plugin to work? 
Another question, I got the same error when I run mvn clean in Linux, I thought junction plugin would use ln -s in Linux, why it's still looking for junction.exe? 
Thanks in advance!

David

Answer (score 0):

You can try manually installing/deploying `junction.exe` in local `.m2` or `archiva` respectively.

To manually `install` in your local repository you can run the `mvn install:install-file` goal of [maven install plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/).  To `deploy` in archiva, you can use `mvn deploy:deploy-file` command of [maven deploy plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/).  Alternately, archiva may have web based deploy option which can be used as well.  In either case, you need to specify the following parameters:

- `groupId` as `sysinternals`,
- `artifactId` as `junction`,
- `version` as `1.04`
- `type` as `exe`.

As for why it is looking for the exe even on linux, looking at the [pom file](https://pyx4j.com/viewvc/pyx4j/pyx4j-maven-plugins/maven-junction-plugin/pom.xml?revision=3190&view=markup) of the plugin, the dependency on the `exe` is unconditional.  I suspect it will not be actually used in linux.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you expand on "manually installing/deploying" part a bit more?

Comment: @DavidZhao Whit "manual install" you'd place that file into your local .m2 repository folder, so the plugin would calm down if it sees the exe file there. I'll try that soon.